# DropDownList with Two SqlDataSources

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a single dropdownlist with EnableAutoPostBack and two SqlDataSources.

What I am trying to do is if user chooses radiobuttonRed then the DDLType will use SqlDataSourceRed and display data into a gridview depending on DDLTYpe item selected.

If the user chooses radiobuttonBlue then the DDLType will use SqlDataSourceBlue and display the data into a gridview depending on DDLTYpe item selected.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need two SqlConnection objects with connection strings to each database:

```
SqlConnection connRed = new SqlConnection();
SqlConnection connBlue = new SqlConnection();
DataTable dt = null;
SqlDataAdapter da = null;

if(radioButtonRed.Checked)
{
    dt = new DataTable();
    da = new SqlDataAdapter("select command", connRed);   
}
else
{    
    dt = new DataTable();
    da = new SqlDataAdapter("select command", connBlue);
}

da.Fill(dt);
dgv.DataSource = dt;
dgv.DataBind();
```

Comment: The problem here is that you are using two Gridviews. I want to use one gridview, is it possible?

Comment: I've updated my answer to use one `DataGridView` and Fill the `DataTable` appropriately.

Comment: DataTable dt = null;
SqlDataAdapter da = null; should i do this is giving an error since they are not used

Comment: you might want to finish it off with: dgv.databind

Comment: @nocturns2 Thanks for pointing that out. I had forgotten to call `DataBind()` since I forgot this was ASP.NET and not Windows Forms. In Windows Forms, it's not explicitly needed to call `DataBind()`.

Comment: Should I put this in   protected void rbChoice_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: If that is the event that you want this code to be called, then yes. It will be called on `PostBack` since you set the `AutoPostBack` property to true.